# Add existing variable to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got this HTML

```
<div class="calListChip" id="label-bDd1aDFjNnQ2aHFxOTN2cGQyM2JhaXA2cmtAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ" title="Testkalender1">
<div class="calListChip" id="label-OWFmbmdwbWprbTRxMmFrOTNycGlicmM2bjBAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ" title="Testkalender2">
```

and I've got this code, creating variables with the title of a html div as name and then I pass the label of the html object as parameter to the variable.

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByClassName('calListChip');

var view1 = [];

//For each element found
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    //Variable names cant inlude spaces
    var title = elements[i].title;    
    title = title.replace(/ +/g, "");

    //create the variable
    window[title] = elements[i].id;

    //if 'test' exist in the title, add the variable to an array
    if (elements[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf("test") >= 0)
    {
        view1.push(window[title]);   
    }
};
```

But the view1 array dosent get the variable reference but instead a string with the title name, that I cant use later on.

This is the result I want

```
view1 : [Testkalender1, Testkalender2]
```

This is the result i get

```
view1 : ["Testkalender1", "Testkalender2"]
```

The problem is that i dont know how many or the title/label of the html elements so i need to dynamically create variables and then by a keyword in the title put them in the right array

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say you want `view1 : [Testkalender1, Testkalender2]`, what are `Testkalender1` and `Testkalender2` supposed to be?  What javascript type are they?  Strings?  Objects?  Arrays?  DOM Elements?  Numbers?  And where did they come from?  If you somehow want them to be references to a global variable, Javascript does not have that feature.

Comment: Solved it by myself, but thanks to your questioning. The variables Testkalender1 and Testkalender2 was working the whole time, but i didnt understand it since i didnt debug and checked the view1 array when i manually typed it. Sorry for wasting your time but it helped my understand the code better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how exactly you want to generate your desired result (e.g. where the data comes from), but I can help explain what is happening with your current code.  When you do this:

```
window[title] = elements[i].id;
```

You are creating a global variable of name `title` and assigning it the string value located in `elements[i].id`.  So, now you have a global variable with a string in it.

When you later do this:

```
view1.push(window[title])
```

You are just pushing a copy of that string in the `view1` array.  That string has nothing to do with your global variable.  So, `view1` will end up being an array of strings.

---

If you want `view1` to end up being an array of objects like your example here:

```
view1[0] = {
    name: 'TestKalendrar',
    items: [Testkalender1, Testkalender2]
};
```

Then, you have to push objects into the array, not strings.

---

I should add that I have no idea what your creation of global variables with this line:

```
window[title] = elements[i].id;
```

is doing to help you with your problem in any way.  It should not be necessary.

---

I'd be happy to help you get a different result, but so far you've shown a desired array of objects, but not shown us where you get the `name` property from or the `items` property.  If you can edit your question to show where those values come from, we can help with a solution to generate that.

Comment: Yes i figured that aswell but i dont know how im supposed to do it :)

Comment: I'll second that confusion; the `window[title]` part makes no sense to me.

Comment: @user3884316 - please see the last paragraph in my answer.  You need to explain more about where the items in your array of objects come from.  So far, you've only shown `elements[i].id` and `elements[i].title`, but I have no idea how those relate to the `name` and `items` properties in our desired output array of objects.

Comment: This is the original script that i try to make dynamic, and depending on a keyword in the title i want to pass the variable to different views. http://jsfiddle.net/7en3Q/ hope it makes it clearer!

Comment: @jfriend00 the name property is used later as the name of a html link created by the script and the item properties should be the variables created in the loop. you can fint the whole script that im trying to make dynamic here http://jsfiddle.net/7en3Q/3/

Comment: @user3884316 - you're going to have to use some words to describe how you get from the HTML to your `views[0]` object.  The two element HTML sample you show has two divs with different id values and different titles.  How is the code supposed to know to put them both in the same object with yet a different name?  You must describe the algorithm in words for how you understand the HTML and know which items to put together into the same object.  Once I know what algorithm you're actually trying to use, it will be no problem to put that into code, but you have not yet described enough.

Comment: I edited my question to display that, simply put, when i create the variables with window[title] = elements[i].id; i also want to put it into an array, as ive shown with the result i want.

Comment: @user3884316 - what exactly is your question?  I don't understand what you want help with or what you're trying to accomplish.  Your current code creates an array of the title strings.  What do you want in the array.  You can't put a global variable into an array.  You can put the contents of a global variable into an array which is what you are already doing.  I have no idea what your `views[0]` example is about.  I thought you were saying that is what you are trying to achieve.  If so, then were do the `name` and `items` properties in that come from?

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your code a little and indeed the variables are being created see the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/smylydon/Q5m6Q/

var elements = document.body.getElementsByClassName('calListChip');

var view1 = [];

//For each element found
for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {

```
//Variable names cant inlude spaces
var title = elements[i].title;
title = title.replace(/ +/g, "");

//create the variable
window[title] = elements[i].id;

//if 'test' exist in the title, add the variable to an array
if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf("test") >= 0) {
    view1.push(window[title]);
    console.log('variable:', window[title]);
}
```

};

console.log('view1:', view1);

Comment: Yes, but how can i add the variable objects to an array? Not as a string.

Comment: Instead of: window[title] = elements[i].id do window[title] = elements[i] or window.arr = elements;